# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str' in the given code

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

```
import json
def pretty(obj):
    return json.dumps(obj,sort_keys = True, indent = 2)
d = {'key1':{'c':True,'a':90,5:50},'key2':{'b':3,'c':"yes"}}
print(d)
print(pretty(d))
```

Comment: That error message is about as helpful as any answer here is likely to be. Some of the keys are of type `str` and some of `int`, which are not comparable.

Comment: Whats your question, and what are you expecting as output?

Comment: The expected output is a json file made of the string in the variable d

Answer (score 3):

Keys in the dictionary should be string. dictionary at key1 with key 5 is not string. Please replace line below:

```
d = {'key1':{'c':True,'a':90,'5':50},'key2':{'b':3,'c':"yes"}}
```

where 5 is inside single quote